# Apache camel developer console

Tags: apache-camel, camel-core

Apache camel has added camel developer console in their latest release(3.15.0)
I was trying it but after adding dependencies and 'camel.main.dev-console-enabled = true' , I am not able to find the developer console I had tried with endpoint http://localhost:8080/dev

Also I am not able to enable dev console when I am using Camel Context wrote in XML DSL.
How can i add statement to enable developer console when i have camel context written in XML DSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a very new feature, for now, the developer console is only available from http://localhost:8080/dev when you use **Camel JBang** as mentioned [in the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-console.html#_dev_console_and_camel_jbang).

For other modes, you can enable it programmatically by calling `context.setDevConsole(true)` or in case of **Camel Main** by setting `camel.main.dev-console-enabled` to `true` (as you mentioned) but it is not yet exposed, it can only be accessed programmatically from the `DevConsoleRegistry` (accessible with `context.getExtension(DevConsoleRegistry.class)`).